# how Imitate RCTRL + "f" pressing

Tags: vbscript, keypress

This is not what I need:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys("^{f}")
```

It popups search form.

<kbd>RCTRL</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> - sets my window form to full screen, so,

How can I get imitation of <kbd>RCTRL</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> keys press?

Answer (score -1):

In Form_load add the following two lines:

```
Me.BorderStyle = vbBSNone
Me.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```